# irb does not have access to my models (NameError: uninitialized constant)

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am receiving this error when trying to create a new 'Pin' in IRB. For example:

```
irb(main):001:0> @pin = Pin.first
NameError: uninitialized constant Pin
```

OR

```
irb(main):001:0> @pin = Pin.new
NameError: uninitialized constant Pin
```

I must of changed something as it was working before. Unfortunately, I cannot find the error

Here is my pins controller:

```
  class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end

  def show
    @pin = Pin.find params[:id]
  end

  def new
    @pin = Pin.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @pin = Pin.new(pin_params)
    if @pin.save
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @pin.update(pin_params)
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to pins_url
  end

  private

  # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
  def set_pin
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
  end

  def correct_user
    @pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not allowed!" if @pin.nil?
  end

  # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
  def pin_params
    params.require(:pin).permit(:description)
  end
end
```

Here is are my associations, pin.rb

```
class Pin < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end
```

And my associations for User.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :pins
end
```

and my routes

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :pins
  devise_for :users
  root "pages#home"

  get "about" => "pages#about"

end
```

Comment: I don't think you want `IRB`, I think you want `rails c`

Comment: How embarrassing, Oh well. Early days!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`irb` does not automatically load your Rails environment, which is why it does not have access to your models (or helpers, or database, or anything else).  However, the "rails console" is an irb session that does load all of your Rails classes, database connections, etc.

To start the rails console:

```
rails c
```

Which is shorthand for:

```
rails console
```

This starts the rails console for your development environment.  You can make it connect to your test environment:

```
rails c RAILS_ENV=test
```

or to your production environment:

```
rails c RAILS_ENV=production
```